# Attempt to present <UIAlertController: 0x79151e00> on <Prisoners_Dillema.ControllerGame: 0x788b1a00> whose view is not in the window hierarchy

Tags: ios, swift

I'm a beginning swift developer, so bear with me here.

I have a multiplayer game app, and from my server (yes, this is a background thread) I receive a signal that a match has been found. Then this snippet is executed

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        print("showing dialog")
        let dialog = UIAlertController(title: "Game found", message: "You are playing with a person named "+self.player2.getName(), preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        dialog.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil))
        self.presentViewController(dialog, animated: true, completion: nil)
        self.labelOpponentName.text = self.player2.getName()
    })
```

However, I get the following error

```
Attempting to load the view of a view controller while it is deallocating is not allowed and may result in undefined behavior (<UIAlertController: 0x79151e00>)
```

Also, my labelOpponentName is not updating it's text. Why is that?

Comment: What is `self`?  Is it a view controller on the view stack?

Comment: where have you put that block ?

Answer (score 0):

There may be another UIAlertController defined inside your function or globally.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        print("showing dialog")
        let dialog = UIAlertController(title: "Game found", message: "You are playing with a person named "+self.player2.getName(), preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        dialog.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil))
        self.presentViewController(dialog, animated: true, completion: nil)
        self.labelOpponentName.text = self.player2.getName()
    })
```